# Handlebar : Accessing parent scope from child scope

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js

Below is the `Object` I am passing to my `handlebar`:

```
{
    "parent_scope_name": "Parent Scope",
    "parent_scope_id": "240", 
    "child_terms": [
        {
            "value": "some random value",
            "id": "19512",
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I am doing below:

```
{{#each child_terms}}
      <p>child term value::{{value}}</p>
      <p>child term id  :: {{id}}</p>
      <p>Now the next line I need to get parent scope name which is in parent scope. I tried as below. does not work</p>
      <p>{{../parent_scope_name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Please tell how can I access `parent_scope_name` from child term context.

Thanks

Comment: Your code is OK. I think that your problem is in another place: https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/gyrjqrek/
Put the code that you have used to compile the template and add it to the `DOM`.

Comment: Yup. It works great on the jsfiddle. I am confused as to why it is not working correctly with my application.
Just one more info: the template above is in a handlebar partial which I am calling under each scope of child_terms

Comment: Mmm, try to update your question with the rest of the code or use the same `jsfiddle` that I've prepared to reproduce your issue.